# Bypass SSL certificate pinning cause WebView error

Tags: android, security, ssl-certificate, xposed, xposed-framework

I rooted my phone using Magisk Delta and installed all the necessary components, including LSPosed.

I used a repo (https://modules.lsposed.org/module/io.github.tehcneko.sslunpinning) to bypass SSL pinning and it was successful.

I can intercept all HTTPS traffic from the app except when it involves the WebView component which triggers an onReceivedError (ERR_FAILED) and gets stuck on it.

Has anyone else encountered this issue?

Comment: Hey, your question seems to be missing a lot of context. What is the specific error? What is the context of the error (where are you getting it? is there a stack trace? What else is going on when you get the error?). What is the app you are intercepting network traffic for? Is there a particular type of data that you need to see?

Did you follow a set of instructions when doing Magisk Delta and its "necessary components"? What are those instructions?

How did you use the repo you linked?

Comment: @justhecuke I got the same issue. There is an error: "Could not find suitable trust manager". And it looks like 
"Error creating trust manager (io.github.tehcneko.sslunpinning.SSLUnpinning$1): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Required method checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[], String, String, String) missing"

Comment: That module seems to be outdated and it seems to originate form Github but the source code can not be found there, so it had beeen deleted or is a private repo. As alternatives you can use https://github.com/ViRb3/TrustMeAlready or https://github.com/Fuzion24/JustTrustMe